# Environment variables (certifictaes) not being working in Kubernetes which are passed in dpeloy.yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am passing certificates in Java environment variables in deploy.yaml but the Kubernetes container is not able the pick the certificates which are passed as Java_Options . Can anyone assist why the Kubernetes container is not able to pick the certificates which are passed in JAVA_OPTIONS. Now I am passing in JAVA code explicitly, but I don't want to pass the certificates in java code.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILE
          value: cids-migration
        - name: JAVA_MAIN_CLASS
          value: com.agcs.cids.Application
        - name: JAVA_OPTIONS
          value: >-
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
            -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.pkcs12
            -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

Docker File :

```
EXPOSE 8103
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS=""
RUN pwd && ls -lrt
#COPY target/lib/* /deployments/lib/
COPY /*.jar /opt/jboss/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Java :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  // Set system properties via commandline or programmatically

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "<path_to_keystore>");

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "<keystore_password>");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your deploy.yaml, JAVA_OPTIONS contains something like sub environment variable. I assume your java program expects env var "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" but instead it has JAVA_OPTIONS="javax.net.ssl.keyStore=<path_to_keystore>".

To achieve something like below
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "<path_to_keystore>");
Break JAVA_OPTIONS in multiple ENV name-value pairs like
spec:
containers:
- env:
- name: javax.net.ssl.keyStore
value: <path_to_keystore>